# Is there a way to bring edges (with arrows) in front of the nodes in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have created a MultiDiGraph with nodes of varying sizes according to their 'score'. Some of these are quite large and hide the arrows linking them.

I have tried adjusting transparency but it still doesn't look how I want and I'd like it if the edge layer could be brought forwards, is this possible? My other problem is the labels are also overlapping and in the way, ideally I'd like them to be placed below the circle of the node but even changing the vertical alignment that doesn't seem to put them below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @banananada Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)